# Хочу зделать так чтоб все фото из поля "Gallery" загружались и выводились лично к пользователю. Скорее всего это надо указать както ключем во views

Tags: django, multiple

```
models.py
class ProfileGallery(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    gallery = models.ImageField(upload_to='users/gallery/', null=True, blank=True)

forms.py
class ProfileGalleryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ProfileGallery
        fields = ('gallery',)
        widgets = {'gallery': forms.FileInput(attrs={'allow multiple selected': True})}

views.py
def my_page(request, pk):
    user = User.objects.get(id=pk)
    images = ProfileGallery.objects.all()# я уверен здесь проблема
    context = {'user': user, 'images': images}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        delete = DeleteAll(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if delete.is_valid():
            images.delete()
    return render(request, 'account/my_page.html', context)

естественно все фото сограняются в БД, и выводятся все. Получается что все фото это общие фото.
вот на всякий пожарный форма для сохраненияе фото
views.py
def edit(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserEditForm(instance=request.user, data=request.POST)
        profile_form = ProfileEditForm(instance=request.user.profile, data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)
        gallery_form = ProfileGalleryForm(instance=request.user.profile, data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)
        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid() and gallery_form.is_valid():
            user_form.save()
            profile_form.save()
            for uploaded_file in request.FILES.getlist('gallery'):
                ProfileGallery.objects.create(gallery=uploaded_file)
            return redirect('my_page', request.user.pk)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)